# Strange memory usage when using CacheEntryProcessor and modifying cache entry

Tags: memory-leaks, ignite

I wonder if anybody can explain what is going wrong with my code.
I have an IgniteCache of Long->Object[] which is a kind of batching mechanism.

The cache is onheap,partitioned and has one backup configured.

I want to modify some of the objects within the cache entry value array.
So I wrote and implementation of CacheEntryProcessor

```
@Override
    public Object process(MutableEntry<Long, Object[]> entry, Object... arguments)
                    throws EntryProcessorException {
        boolean updated = false;
        int key = (int)arguments[0];
        Set<Long> someIds = Ignition.ignite().cluster().nodeLocalMap().get(key);

        Object[] values = entry.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            Person p = (Person) values[i];
            if (someIds.contains(p.getId())) {
                p.modify();
                if (!updated) {
                    updated = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (updated) {
            entry.setValue(values);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When the cluster is loaded with data each node consumes around 20GB of heap.
When I run the cache processor with cache.invokeAll on multiple node cluster I have a crazy memory behavior - when the processor is being run I see memory usage going up to even 48GB or higher eventually leading to node separation from the cluster cause GC took too long.

However, if I remove the `entry.setValue(values)` line, which stores back the modified array into the cache everything is ok, apart from the fact that the data will not be replicated since the cache is not aware of the change - the update is only visible on the primary node :(

Can anybody tell me how to make it work? What is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not recommend to allocate large heap sizes. This will very likely cause a long GC pause even if everything is working properly. Basically, JVM will not clean up memory until it reaches certain threshold, and when it does reach, there will be to much garbage to collect. Try switching to off-heap or start more Ignite nodes.

The fact that more garbage is generated in case you update the entry, makes perfect sense. Basically each time you update you replace old value with a new one, and the old one becomes garbage.

If none of this helps, grab a heap dump and check what is occupying the memory.

Comment: Sure, I am aware of the different issues when using big heaps but so far it has not been a big deal for us. We run in memory map reduce jobs that create some statistics on the objects stored in cache - on-heap was simply faster than off-heap given the same hardware setup - we always cruch all the data. Can u explain how entry.setValue works internally? What is happening behind this call? For me it looks like there must be somewhere a copy of the object created or serialized cause I noticed objects appearing immediately in the old gen(must be due to their sizes).

Comment: Asking because I am modifying the original array and not creating new objects and storing them via setValue. According to setValue's code it is assigning oldVal to the previous value and val to the new one so I wonder where the new objects are coming from.

Comment: Yes, a copy is created when you get the value, and `setValue` replaces the old value with the new one.

Comment: That is unfortunately what I was thinking was happening. Is there any way I could workaround it apart from adding more boxes? Moving the cache to offheap does not help apparently. I am storing millions of objects in the cache (they are batched, so each entry is pretty big) and I want to update some of them. Appreciate any hints!!!

Comment: You can set `CacheConfiguration.setCopyOnRead(false)` to avoid copy creation. However, mutating the instance that is stored in cache is not safe as it can be concurrently serialized. Also if you do not call `setValue`, Ignite will not recognize this as an update and you will not have any guarantees.